# How to increment the folder number if folder already exist in a directory

Tags: c#

Ex. If I created a folder with a folder name of IMG10001 but it was already exist in the target directory. The code below will make the folder name to IMG10001-1 but what I like to accomplish is to increment the folder name to IMG10002 if IMG10001 already exist in the target directory.

```
string destinDir = dirPath + "\\" + this.Batch.BatchName;
int x = 0;
if (Directory.Exists(destinDir))
{
    do
    {
        x++;
        destinDir = dirPath + "\\" + this.Batch.BatchName + "-" + x.ToString();
    } while (Directory.Exists(destinDir));
}    
System.IO.Directory.Move(root,destinDir);
```

Comment: You need to read what to value in first so you can increment it fron there... And remove the dash from the file name.

Comment: You're suppose to replace the name of the file, not append values to it. You want something like IMG1002 ... I don't see a dash there.

Comment: Ah so what's your suggestion then I am asking how could I change the code so I will have the result that I like, as I pointed out the code will not rename the folder if a duplicate filenumber already exist, the code will give a IMG10001-1, note that this code is use in a live production setting. this  destinDir = dirPath + "\\" + this.Batch.BatchName + "-" + x.ToString();
will give you a result of IMG10001-1.

Answer (score 2):

```
//regular expression will work
Regex reg = new Regex("IMG(\\d+)$");
Match m = reg.match(this.Batch.BatchName);
int num = 10001;
if(m.success){
    int.tryParse(m.Groups[1].value,out num);
}
Return string.format("IMG{0}",num);
```

I just write these code in the input box, I haven't tried. but I think it should work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that BatchName always starts with "IMG", you can split the number out of the file. To make sure you get the highest number, loop through all the files and store the highest number found.

Once you have found the highest number, increment it by 1 and rebuild you filename ("IMG" + newNumber).

Comment: the batchname will be index starting with IMG10001...IMG1nnnn

Answer (score 1):

you can extract integer part from your string using `Regex` and increment it as

```
string YourString = "IMG10001";
int IntegerPart = Convert.ToInt16(Regex.Match(s, "\\d+").ToString());
IntegerPart++;
```

Comment: Need to use this with `IntegerPart.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0')`, or similar, in order to get the string in the right format.